# OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f5b2d2d9e60>

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, lmdb

I created a lmdb dataset of images and labels but on reading the images, it is giving me error which I can't understand. The images have been checked and no problems have been found.

Code:

```
    index += 1
    with self.env.begin(write=False) as txn:
        img_key = 'image-%09d' % index
        imgbuf = txn.get(img_key.encode())
        #print(type(imgbuf))
        buf = six.BytesIO()
        buf.write(imgbuf)
        buf.seek(0)
        try:    
            img = Image.open(buf).convert('L')
        except IOError:
            print('Corrupted image for %d' % index)
            return self[index + 1]

        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)

        label_key = 'label-%09d' % index
        label = str(txn.get(label_key))

        if self.target_transform is not None:
            label = self.target_transform(label)
```

Stack Trace:

```
File "crnn_main.py", line 196, in
cost = trainBatch(crnn, criterion, optimizer)
File "crnn_main.py", line 171, in trainBatch
data = train_iter.next()
File "/home/jethodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 264, in next
batch = self.collate_fn([self.dataset[i] for i in indices])
File "/home/jethodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 264, in
batch = self.collate_fn([self.dataset[i] for i in indices])
File "/home/jethodh/Documents/crnn.pytorch-master/dataset.py", line 52, in getitem
img = Image.open(buf)
File "/home/jethodh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2622, in open
% (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f5b2d2d9e60>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't see any problems in your code - are you sure that the error isn't exactly what it says it is, a problem with the image in question?

Comment: @radarhere I checked out the images as well to check if something was wrong with them. There isn't any problem with them at all. When I run this code, the except code block runs and gives me this error for every image until recursion error.

Comment: Okay, then. What is txn?

Comment: @radarhere Check the edited code.